# Cicros plot issue using two data track

Tags: circos

Im trying to plot log fold change for a condition as well as no of patient for a particular gene mutated information but whenever im trying to do that i see only only the fold changes labeling not the patient but my idea is to see the fold change as well as mutation information for that gene im posting the .conf file along with the data files im using any help would be highly appreciated .

Or there is a flaw in my idea to show both of them which im not sure but i guess whatever i seen so far examples it can work!

My conf file code and my data files [data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZoOR-QusndH-Pwqs-WnkCGRTcOsJTULW)

```
use_rules = yes
karyotype = data/karyotype/karyotype.human.txt
# spacing = 10000000
#
# you can write
#
# spacing = 10u
#
# See ticks.conf for examples.

chromosomes_units = 1000000
#chromosomes_display_default = no
#chromosomes                 = /hs[1234]$/
#chromosomes=hs5;hs7; hs17; hs11; hs9

<<include ideogram.conf>>

<<include four_ticks_4chr.conf>>

<image>
<<include etc/image.conf>>                
</image>
<<include etc/colors.conf>> 

<<include etc/colors_fonts_patterns.conf>> 




<<include etc/housekeeping.conf>> 

<plots>
<plot>
#this is for two direction expression data visualisation
type = histogram 
#file=data2/HSC_VS_CMP.txt
#file = /home/punit/circos-0.69-5/data_files/LEUKEMIA_value_tab.txt
file = /home/punit/circos-0.69-5/data_files/CIRCOS_VAL1.txt

r0   = 0.60r
r1   = 0.35r
thickness = 10
min=-1.5
max=1.5
extend_bin = no

<rules>
<rule>
condition    = var(value) > 1.5
color        = dred
fill_color   = dred
</rule>

<rule>
condition    = var(value) < -1.5
color        = dgreen
fill_color   = dgreen
</rule>
</rules>
</plot>
#########################################################

###########################################################


<plot>
type    = text
color = black
#file = /home/punit/circos-0.69-5/LEUKEMIA_gene_tab.txt
file = /home/punit/circos-0.69-5/CIRCOS_LOC1.txt


r0   = 0.75r
r1   = 0.95r
show_links     = yes
link_dims      = 0p,0p,50p,0p,10p
# link_dims      = 4p,4p,8p,4p,4p
link_thickness = 2p
link_color     = grey
label_snuggle             = yes
max_snuggle_distance      = 2r
label_size   = 25p
label_font   = condensed
padding  = 0p
rpadding = 0p
</plot>

###############################################################################


#############################################################################################

    <plot>
    #this is for two direction expression data visualisation
    type = histogram
    color = blue
    #file=data2/HSC_VS_CMP.txt
    #file = /home/punit/circos-0.69-5/data_files/LEUKEMIA_value_tab.txt
    file = /home/punit/circos-0.69-5/M_DATA.txt

    r0 = 2.0r
    r1 = 1.8r
    orientation = out

    #max       = 20
    #min       = -20
    stroke_type = outline
    thickness   = 18
    extend_bin  = yes
    fill_color = blue

    <rules>
    <rule>
    condition    = var(value) > 10
    color        = dblue
    fill_color   = dblue
    </rule>

    <rule>
    condition    = var(value) < 8
    color        = dyellow
    fill_color   = dyellow
    </rule>
    </rules>

    </plot>






    </plots>
```