# Circos plot with mutation data

Tags: circos

This was my earlier [question](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/5661/cicros-plot-issue-using-two-data-track) but now I would like to see patient sample mutation which i have tried and im getting an output but it looks really dumb [image: Circos output]

So here are my data files and conf file [files](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZoOR-QusndH-Pwqs-WnkCGRTcOsJTULW)

In my file which im trying to plot is gene having mutation in terms of patient which ranges from 1  to 53 patient at max .

NPM1 is having the highest mutation with 53 patient in the plot what i tried is to set a threshold of between > 10 and < 3 to set the color label ,which labels the number it contains.

1. How can i add the gene names to the plot ?
2. Is there a way where i can show the genes with only 1 mutation are linked together ,similarly for 2 linked together so on and so forth .

I tried with the links but couldn;t make it work.

Any suggestion or help would be highly appreciated .